# MySQL Sorting by turns

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I want to sort the following data items in the order they are presented below :

```
id | res
--------
1     A
2     A
3     A
4     A
5     A
6     B
7     B
8     B
9     B
10    B
11    C
12    C
13    C
14    C
15    C
```

And i want the output is :

```
res
---
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
```

Any tricks to make it sort more properly?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can order by the "rank" within the group. The rank can be calculated using a self join and counting the entries with lesser ids.

```
select t1.id, t1.res
from mytable t1
join mytable t2
  on  t2.res = t1.res
  and t2.id <= t1.id
group by t1.id, t1.res
order by count(*), t1.res
```

http://rextester.com/ICHZNN18920

Comment: Great, It was very kind of you
Thank you a lot

Comment: How if my query :

Comment: How if my query :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnP6N.png

and i want output (nomor) :

01
02
03
01
02
03

Comment: How if my query : 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnP6N.png 

and i want output (nomor) : 

<pre>

Comment: How if my query : 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnP6N.png 

and i want output (nomor) : 01 02 03 01 02 03 01 02 03

Thanks before

Comment: You can do like that : select * 
from ( yourSelect1 union yourSelect2 union yourSelect 3 ) as t1
join  ( yourSelect1 union yourSelect2 union yourSelect 3 ) as  t2
  on  t2.nomor = t1.nomor  and t2.id <= t1.id
group by t1.id, t1.res
order by count(*), t1.res

Comment: @KemalD. This is "a bit" more complicated. Imanez' comment should work. But you better write a new question.

Comment: this my questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40061173/mysql-sorting-by-turns-query

Comment: Sounds like you need to pivot, transpose, then unpivot.  How to do those?  I don't now.