# MySQL Sorting by turns query

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I want to sort the following data items in the order they are presented below :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnP6N.png)

```
id      msisdn          locker     is_selected  classification  nomor
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1282    62811409xxx    Kendari         0             1           01
1138    62811409xxx    Kendari         0             1           01
3264    62811556xxx    Samarinda       0             1           02
3323    62811562xxx    Pontianak       0             1           02
3450    62811481xxx    Jayapura        0             1           03
3435    62811481xxx    Jayapura        0             1           03
```

Query :

```
(SELECT *, CONCAT(is_selected, 1) AS nomor FROM reference_number WHERE is_selected = 0 AND classification = 1 AND
LEFT(msisdn, 7) IN (6281140, 6281141, 6281142, 6281143, 6281144, 6281145, 6281146) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2) UNION

(SELECT *, CONCAT(is_selected, 2) AS nomor FROM reference_number WHERE is_selected = 0 AND classification = 1 AND
LEFT(msisdn, 7) IN (6281150, 6281151, 6281152, 6281153, 6281154, 6281155, 6281156, 6281157, 6281158, 6281159) 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2) UNION

(SELECT *, CONCAT(is_selected, 3) AS nomor FROM reference_number WHERE is_selected = 0 AND classification = 1 
AND LEFT(msisdn, 7) IN (6281147, 6281148, 6281149) 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)

ORDER BY nomor
```

And i want the output is :

```
nomor
-----
01
02
03
01
02
03
01
02
03
```

Any tricks to make it sort more properly?

Many Thanks!

Comment: You question is not clear you want the result orber by nomor  .. order  by somethings others??? your out is not in order by nomor .

Comment: Actually i want to show data msisdn by turns with output : 62811409xxx
62811556xxx
62811481xxx
62811409xxx
62811562xxx
62811481xxx

Comment: How will you turn 6 rows into 9?