# PHP Sorting by turns

Tags: php, sorting

I want to sort the following data items in the order they are presented below :

```
$char = array('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C');
```

And i want the output is :

```
$char = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C');
```

Any tricks to make it sort with PHP

Many Thanks!

Comment: Google this => "how to sort an array in php".

Comment: You also seem to be posting quite a few similar posts related to sorting. Your first being http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060102/mysql-sorting-by-turns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Sorting by turns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060102/mysql-sorting-by-turns)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool sort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )
```

This function sorts an array. Elements will be arranged from lowest to highest when this function has completed.

Try this:

```
$char = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C');
sort($char);
print_r($char);
```

Credit: [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Comment: Really wishing you well with this. OP posted the same / similar questions ever since they started.

Comment: But i want sort by turn like this : A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort an array in the Ascending order of the values you can use the `asort()` so that it sorts the array in ascending order of the values.

`asort` — Sort an array and maintain index association.

This function sorts an array such that array indices maintain their correlation with the array elements they are associated with. This is used mainly when sorting associative arrays where the actual element order is significant.

**Example Code:**

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");
asort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
?>
```

**Output:**

```
c = apple
b = banana
d = lemon
a = orange
```

Example Reference: [asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

## Solution to your Question

Your Code needs to be like this.

```
<?php
$char = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C');
asort($char);//Sorts the array here
foreach ($char as $key => $val) {
    $values[] = $val;
}
print_r($values);//Print the sorted output
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => A [1] => A [2] => A [3] => A [4] => A [5] => B [6] => B [7] => B [8] => B [9] => B [10] => C [11] => C [12] => C [13] => C [14] => C )
```

Comment: But i want the output is : A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C